# Is there a way to find each URL in a Varchar field's records, pull out specific chars, and replace each entire URL with one that ends in those chars?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, substring

I have a data table called Characteristics with 561 records, that has a column called "FullDescription," each row of which is full of paragraphs featuring one or more URLs that were entered incorrectly. In each row for this column, I need to capture a very specific string, a 6-digit number that exists in each URL, and then replace each entire URL with a very specific URL that ends with that 6 digit numeric value. Each URL to be replaced has 42 characters, and the 6-digit code occupies locations 32 through 37 *relative to the **URL***. Unfortunately, each result contains several URLs, and because it's in paragraph form, there's no way to tell the numeric position of each URL relative to the **result** it's in.

As an example, one result might have 3 URLs in it. This is not the specific data, but each row will have different words in it. Here is an example of what this query might return:

`SELECT FullDesciption`
`FROM Characteristics`
`WHERE ID = 400`

> Here are some words and `http://replace.this.org/number/123456.html` and then they say some more words and you get another URL `http://replace.this.org/number/234567.html` and then it keeps going and more URLs appear `http://replace.this.org/number/999999.html` the end.

I need to find a way to capture each 6-digit number right before the .html for every URL in a result, replace each instance of a URL with a 34 character URL where the first 28 characters are all the same, and the 6-digit number will occupy the last 6 locations, 29 through 34. When all is said and done, after the change, the paragraph above should look like this:

> Here are some words and `https://www.this.org/number/123456` and then they say some more words and you get another URL `https://www.this.org/number/234567` and then it keeps going and more URLs appear `https://www.this.org/number/999999` the end.

I've tried using wildcards that don't seem to work in the search function, but everything I've tried isn't working, and perhaps it required functions I haven't used yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: Proper sample data and expected results would make understanding your question much easier. Also include your current attempt(s), even if not working as desired.

Comment: "and maybe more URLs appear" Maybe? Perhaps a few rows of data with the column names might help here.  Also be sure to include your expected results.

Comment: From the single case you've illustrated, it appears you just need to remove the ".html", replace the http with https and replace the first url segment with "www". Is that correct? If not a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed.

Comment: @jarih gah, I always name things wrong. Anyway, I made some edits. Hopefully that's better.

Comment: You'll find this much easier to solve just about anywhere (i.e. your client code) other than SQL Server.

Comment: @Stu Thank you. I formatted it a bit differently with the query I would use. The first quote above is what would be returned, the 2nd one is what I would like to be returned. I unfortunately didn't retain anything I tried, but I'll probably try again tomorrow if I don't get help, so I can come back with that here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think you are taking the words literally, but I just put any words in there to demonstrate the potential structure of a returned result.

Comment: @Stu That is correct

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that doing this somewhere other than SQL Server using some regex-replace might be preferable, looking at the challenge of doing it in SQL Server the obvious approach is to break the source data into rows with one URL per row, perform the string replacements, and then re-aggregate.

Making use of *OpenJson* to split the string (it provides for dependable ordering) and *String_Agg* to reaggregate yields the following (assuming a fully supported version of SQL Server):

```
select String_Agg(NewDescription, '') within group (order by seq)
from t
cross apply (
  select IsNull(
    Replace(
      Replace(
        j.[value], Left(j.[value], NullIf(CharIndex('.', j.[value]),0) -1), 'https://www'
      ), '.html',''
    ), j.[value]
  ) NewDescription,
  Convert(int, j.[Key]) Seq
  from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(String_Escape(FullDescription, 'json'), 'http://', '","'), '"]')) j
)u;
```

This will almost certainly require some work to deal with edge cases and other content in your source data, but works with what you have provided.

see [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ff73a081a31e2301d11b56acdc5946c)

[image]

Comment: Being freeform text I would suggest that you  string_escape(FullDescription,'JSON') prior to the replace

Comment: Good call, I will add.

Comment: Thank you so much - yeah I realize this is among the least ideal ways to do it, but it works. Thank you!

Comment: If this is not a one-off and you're putting this into production I would suggest moving the json-part into its own table-valued function, same for the cross apply.